# Stream Exercise: average delta of the yearly average temperature per country

Tags: java, stream

a Temperature calss is given (not allowed to modify it):

```java
public class Temperature {
    private final LocalDate date;
    private final double temperature;
    private final String city;
    private final String country;
    // getters   are available
}
```

There is a pre-implemented method called stream() with gives me a  non-null stream of these objects.

I'm tasked to find the average delta of the yearly average temperature per country.

A delta is the difference  between the average of year \$y_i\$ and year \$y_{i+1}\$

In addition, the average over all countries should be stored in the key Globally.

The purpose of these activity is to learn about streams. So loops are forbidden.

criteria: performance > brevity > readability

I've came up with two approaches:

- using TreeMap, problem it's O(n*log n)

```java
public Map < String, Double > avgTemperatureDeltaPerYearPerCountry() {

 Function < Temperature, Integer > getYear = x -> x.getDate().getYear();

 var answer = stream().collect(groupingBy(Temperature::getCountry,
  collectingAndThen(Collectors.groupingBy(getYear, TreeMap::new,
    Collectors.toList()), x -> {
    Function < Map.Entry < Integer,
    List < Temperature >> ,
    Double > average =
    y -> y.getValue().stream().mapToDouble(Temperature::getTemperature)
    .average().getAsDouble();

    return (average.apply(x.lastEntry()) -
     average.apply(x.firstEntry())) / Math.max(x.size() - 1, 1);
   }

  )
 ));

 answer.put("Globally", answer.values().stream().collect(averagingDouble(i -> i)));
 return answer;

}
```

- using teeing, problem it calculates the average for all years instead of only for the first and last one.

```java
public Map < String, Double > avgTemperatureDeltaPerYearPerCountry() {

 Function < Temperature, Integer > getYear = x -> x.getDate().getYear();

 var answer = stream().collect(groupingBy(Temperature::getCountry,
  teeing(
   groupingBy(getYear, averagingDouble(Temperature::getTemperature)),
   teeing(maxBy(Comparator.comparing(getYear)),
          minBy(Comparator.comparing(getYear)), Map::entry),
   (a, b) -> (a.get(getYear.apply(b.getKey().get())) -
   a.get(getYear.apply(b.getValue().get()))) / Math.max(a.size() - 1,1)
  )

 ));

 answer.put("Globally", answer.values().stream().collect(averagingDouble(i -> i)));
 return answer;

}
```

How can I improve thise code, is there a better approach?
Ist it possible to calculate and add the global answer in the same pass?

csv file for test data: https://gofile.io/?c=ugWXIG

Temperatures class to turn the csv file into a stream of Temperature Objects (not my code):  https://ideone.com/GXLhwH

Result:

`{Globally=0.041800897436956246, Cyprus=0.015007500000000036, Portugal=0.024267619047619073, Iceland=0.035724166666666675, Russia=0.05631454594017095, Greece=0.030444285714285754, Austria=0.047424333333333346, Sweden=0.03479516666666667, Netherlands=0.03418625000000002, Ireland=0.026464999999999995, Poland=0.0498942543859649, Slovenia=0.04946666666666665, Slovakia=0.056125416666666685, France=0.03514935185185184, Croatia=0.04781805555555557, Romania=0.05889966666666666, Hungary=0.05899083333333333, Ukraine=0.07034451388888886, Moldova=0.06559138888888888, Belarus=0.062140104166666654, Switzerland=0.03716116666666666, Albania=0.02697416666666669, Spain=0.02474883333333331, Turkey=0.03446887254901967, Belgium=0.03550976190476192, Norway=0.023666875000000004, Finland=0.04395483333333333, Denmark=0.034530416666666654, Italy=0.032463908730158766, Montenegro=0.046323333333333314, Germany=0.03924569958847737, Estonia=0.057730833333333356}`

Comment: Welcome to Code Reveiw! To help reviewers, could you add some example input and output to your question?

Comment: The temperature is missing a bunch of fields

Comment: "criteria: performance > brevity > readability" This makes the code review a bit pointless. Readability and maintainability are the most important criteria. Performance trumps it only when there are very good and measured reasons. Brevity matters only in silly code competitions.

Comment: @tinstaafl I omitted them from the code because they are irrelevant.

Comment: @TorbenPutkonen These are the criteria, upon which code can be evaluated in order to meet the goal of the excercise . If someone comes up with a better way to do it. Than I learned something, that improves my knowledge or presumably  the knowledge of others. that's the  point.

Comment: and even in General Brevity does matter. code that is too verbose is more error prone and slower which is a bad experience for user ( and usually a code smell).  Writing code that is overengineered is also a form of  premature optimization.

Comment: That would be readability, which was on lowest priority.

Comment: How can the missing fields be irrelevant when the `Temperatures` class needs them for the constructor?  You expect people to waste time filling in all that stuff when they're donating their time to try and help you?

Comment: meant irrelevant to the question, as it would add clutter. If I added them to the question body  it would be too long despite  You don't need to fill them in. you just make a constructor with those parameters that just throws those values away when given to him.